# How to pass pytorch loss function to c++ code in pytorch c++ extension?

Tags: c++, pytorch, pybind11

I am using **pytorch c++ extension** to write some logic in the c++ code. But I require the pytorch loss function to be passed from python code. My dummy c++ code is as follows,

```cpp
#include <torch/extension.h>
#include <iostream>

namespace py = pybind11;

torch::Tensor calculateLoss(
    torch::Tensor pred,
    torch::Tensor target,
    <pytorch_loss_fn> fn
){
    return fn(pred,target);
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(TORCH_EXTENSION_NAME, m) {
    m.def("calculateLoss", &calculateLoss, "Calculate Loss In C++");
}
```

And the python code triggering this,

```py
import torch
import stack_cpp

from torch.nn import BCELoss

y_p = torch.Tensor([0.25,0.75])
y = torch.Tensor([0.0,1.0])

print(stack_cpp.calculateLoss(y_p,y,BCELoss()))
```

What is the pytorch way to achieve the same? What datatype should I use in place of `<pytorch_loss_fn>`?

If I were to pass an activation function too (say `torch.Sigmoid()`),  what data type should I use?